# Change Woocommerce 'My Account' page content with CSS

Tags: css, woocommerce

How would I change the default content displayed on Woocommerce when using [woocommerce_my_account] ? Is there CSS code to do this ?

To be more specific, trying to the the two things below:

1) remove red asteriks from 'edit account' fields. I've made them readonly already in the woocommerce php files. [red asteriks screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgGoe.png)

2) Change the font and styling for the buttons that are coded in [woocommerce_my_account], [recent order-my account-button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qg9fe.png)

Thanks!

Comment: I recommend you to provide more information about your concern. Do you want to change the design? do you want to change what is dispalyed on the page? Unfortunately I don't fully understand what you need....

Comment: Hi Sofian, Just updated my question with more information. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to change these things at the point where you import this plugin.

What you need to do is to find out, what class or ID is used on these elements to then change their attributes.

I guess that the little star is displayed by using the pseudo-element `::after`. So in this case you need to find out the class of the element on which this `::after` is set on and change the property `content` to `unset` or to an empty string.

At the end the result should be similar to this:

```css
.the .selector .to .the .element::after {
    content: '';
}
```

or:

```css
.the .selector .to .the .element::after {
    content: unset;
}
```

or:

```css
.the .selector .to .the .element::after {
    display: none;
}
```

If nothing of these helps, try using the `!important` statement, like in the following example:

```css
.the .selector .to .the .element::after {
    display: none !important;
}
```

And for your second concern you would need, again, to look for the correct selector again.
If you don't know how to find out a selector, this is what you need to do:
(I will explain how it works for the browser `Chrome`, but it should be similar with other browsers)

1. look for the element you want to find out the selector
2. right-click the element and click on the penultimate item, which name should be `inspect` (I am using Chrome in german, so I don't exactly know what is written there)
3. the developer-tools should got opened at the right of the chrome window (or at the bottom, it depends on the settings)
4. Hover through the elements at the right until you see that the element you want to change is marked blue as follows:
   [image: marked element]
5. then right click the element and click on `copy` -> 'copy selector'

and voila, you got the right selector.

Hope this helps!
Good luck!